# how do i pass parameters to aspnet reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I want to pass parameters to reportviewer control from the page I built with a form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are lookin for.

```
List<Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter> params = new List<Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter>();


params.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("Name", "Value", false));

this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Url access parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256629(SQL.80).aspx)